# Geopandas sjoin_nearest(). Confusing results using projected CRS

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I am trying to use geopandas sjoin_nearest() to measure distance from a point geodataframe to a line geodataframe. I am confused about the results.

Originally, both of my layers are in the coordinate reference system of 4269. I understand this is is a geographic CRS and is measured in decimal degrees. I then changed the crs of both of these layers to a projected crs, epsg: 32617. This is UTM zone 17N and the study area is on the east coast of the USA. I did so with the following code (seems very simple):

```
points_gdf = points_gdf.to_crs(epsg=32617)
lines_gdf = lines_gdf.to_crs(epsg=32617)
```

Then I run the sjoin_nearest tool using these two layers with the following line of code:

```
points_gdf = points_gdf.sjoin_nearest(lines, distance_col='distance_to_line')
```

This creates the 'distance_to_line' column. However, the results are confusing. When running the following, this clearly shows the units of measurement are in meters:

```
points.crs

<Derived Projected CRS: EPSG:32617>
Name: WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: Between 84°W and 78°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore 
and offshore. Bahamas. Ecuador - north of equator. Canada - Nunavut; Ontario; Quebec. 
Cayman Islands. Colombia. Costa Rica. Cuba. Jamaica. Nicaragua. Panama. United States 
(USA).
- bounds: (-84.0, 0.0, -78.0, 84.0)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: UTM zone 17N
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

The 'distance to line' column should be measuring in meters. The maximum distance should not be more than 1000 meters. However, the values in this column look something like this:  `3995271.6977319703`

It seems to me there is something I don't understand when using the `to_crs()` method. What am I missing?